# Create materialized view with NOT NULL column? (dblink to external table)

Tags: oracle, constraints, materialized-views, dblink, notnull

I've created a materialized view that syncs data from an external system (on a 5 second schedule; via a dblink).

- The primary system that has the MV is Oracle 18c.
- The external system with the source data/dblink is Oracle 19c

---

```
create materialized view log on my_external_sys.workorder with rowid;  --external system 

create materialized view my_primary_sys.wo_mv --primary system 
build immediate 
refresh force 
on demand 
start with sysdate next sysdate + (5/(60*60*24))
as
select
    cast(workorderid as number(38,0)) as objectid,
    wonum,
    status,
    --other fields
    longitudex,
    latitudey
from
    my_external_sys.workorder@gistomax --dblink
```

The materialized view works as expected.

However, I realize now that my primary system has special requirements for its tables (or, in this case, MVs).

- There needs to be a column in tables/MVs called OBJECTID that has the **NOT NULL** constraint.
- More info here: [SDO_GEOMETRY and ArcGIS](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/sdogeometry-feature-classes.htm)

---

Question:

Is there a way to create a materialized view (via a dblink to an external db/table) that has a column with the NOT NULL constriant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the mistake of assuming that `alter table` wouldn't work on an MV.

But it totally works.

```
alter table my_primary_sys.wo_mv modify objectid not null;
```

That was easy.